# SUM of the field multiplies when the main table join with another manyToOne relationship table

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
select sum(t.amount) user_amount_sum 
  from users u
  join investor_transactions t
    on u.id = t.investor_id
 group 
    by u.id;
```

**returns user_amount_sum value 40 for each users. (correct)**

> select sum(investor_transactions.amount) AS user_amount_sum from
>   `users`  **inner join `merchant_user` on `merchant_user`.`user_id` =
>   `users`.`id`**   inner join `investor_transactions` on `users`.`id` =
>   `investor_transactions`.`investor_id`   group by `users`.`id`;

**But now returns user_amount_sum value 200 for each users. (5 times more, there are 5 rows in merchant_user table for each user)**

NB 1: The only difference between both query is

```
inner join `merchant_user` on `merchant_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id
```

NB 2: I'm joining merchant_user table for filtering purpose.

***What is the best practice to solve this issue.?***

Comment: If you are just selecting `sum(investor_transactions.amount)`, why would you need the innerjoin on `merchant_user` table? Do you want to filter and get only the records which have `merchant_user` entry?

Comment: yes, i will have a status to filter in merchant_user table.

Answer (score 1):

SUM, and all aggregate functions, operate on the intermediate result (of the FROM...WHERE); you will encounter this issue any time multiple 1:N relationships are joined. Since you're only using the additional join for filtering, you should be able to use alternatives like:

```
SELECT SUM(investor_transactions.amount) AS user_amount_sum 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN investor_transactions ON users.id = investor_transactions.investor_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM merchant_user) AS mu ON mu.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(investor_transactions.amount) AS user_amount_sum 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN investor_transactions ON users.id = investor_transactions.investor_id 
WHERE users.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM merchant_user) 
GROUP BY users.id;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(investor_transactions.amount) AS user_amount_sum 
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN investor_transactions ON u.id = investor_transactions.investor_id 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM merchant_user AS mu WHERE mu.user_id = u.id) 
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Edit: though now that I look at it, you can probably skip the users table since you're only using the id field from it, like this...

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS user_amount_sum 
FROM investor_transactions AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM merchant_user) AS mu ON t.user_id = mu.user_id
GROUP BY t.user_id;
```

and similar for the other alternatives above.

Comment: Thank you, In my case it is not enough, i have to do some other query with the both relational tables. but I did it with 2 query, and achieved.